# Need search points to split but I need only when didn't match other sub string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying many ways to do that with Regex but I don't have strong skills with regex.

Well my situation is, I have this string `What is this and this is cool`, in this case I need split `is` but I won't split `What is`, I want only split `is` between `this` and `cool`.

I tried with this regex `(?!What)....(\sis\s)` but this will return `this is` and I need only the second `is`.

Thanks advanced

Comment: What about `What is this and this thing is cool` ?

Comment: @revo, I am working with NLP and some people write crazy sentences, and sentences like that broke the flow :(

Comment: I mean what if a `thing` is between `this` and `cool`? Should it split at `is` between them?

Comment: If I apply split on 'is' it will return `What`, `this and this`, `cool` and I expected return `What is this and this` `cool `, I need the first thing after is and the first thing after this is wrong :(

Comment: Please read my sample input carefully *What is this and this **thing** is cool* and say whether or not it should split at second `is`.

Comment: what is the general case you try to handle ?

Comment: I am trying handle situation when I have some words to split, but I won't split when match specify word before like `What` in this case, I just only want understand how to do that because I want to create others patterns

Comment: I don't know if you it's possible to have a pretty regex, but you can split your string on `" "` to get all words, then in a loop search for the 'is' occurences, and handle your custom rules.

Comment: I will do that.. but I have hope :P thanks for your time

Comment: Check if this is what you are trying to do http://jsbin.com/koqozozebi/edit?js,console

Comment: You need to construct groups with positive or negative LookBehind. 
[see answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups)
for example `(?<!What)\sis`  will return first occurence of " is " not preceded by "what"
`(?<=this)\sis\s` will return first occurence of " is " preceded by "this"

Comment: Some crazy workaround, see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9m90sr7k/6/).

Comment: Thanks guys, scraaappy I think ?< isn't work on javascript. revo very nice regex, I will study it and test some cases in my server, Wiktor Stribiżew I will read your workaround maybe it will resolve to me..

Comment: Did below answer help? or should I improve or remove it?

Answer (score 1):

### TL; DR

A one-liner regex solution:

```
(?:\bis\b)?((?:(?!\bis\b)(?:What\s+is\b)?.?)+)
```

[Regex live demo](https://regex101.com/r/gSlO8m/1)

JS code:

```js
var re = /(?:\bis\b)?((?:(?!\bis\b)(?:What\s+is\b)?.?)+)/;
console.log(
  "What is this and is What is this is cool What is this is"
  .split(re)
  .filter(Boolean)
);
```

### Whole philosophy

This regex tries to match a `is` word as soon as it steps into one otherwise it will continue matching a `What is` occurrence or other characters as long as they are not `is`. It matches and captures anything other than `is`.

The trick here is using a tempered token to see if next occurrence is a `is` or not. If not, try to match a `What is` or a single character. This process continues up to meeting a `is`.

- `(?:\bis\b)?` Try to match a word `is`
- `(` Start of capturing group #1

  - `(?:` Start of non-capturing group

    - `(?!\bis\b)` Look if next word is `is`
    - `(?:What\s*is\b)?.?` If not try to match `What is` or a single character or nothing
  - `)+` Repeat as many as possible
- `)` End of capturing group #1

[`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method considers matched parts in capturing group to output array, hence matching `is` in regex and capturing anything else.

To avoid splitting on different words other than `What` you only need to add each word in an alternation within a group:

```
(?:\bis\b)?((?:(?!\bis\b)(?:(?:What|How|Who)\s+is\b)?.?)+)
```

You may need to set `i` flag in order to capture `what is` too if you want or splitting happens.